# Cannot install postgres on Ubuntu (E: Unable to locate package postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.10

So I'm having this problem where for some reason I can't install any package on my ubuntu system.
I'm currently on `Ubuntu 16.10`.

terminal install logs

[image: terminal install logs]

---

Update:

I've done entered those commands and got this.

after update and apt-cache

[image: after update and apt-cache]

What should I do now?

Comment: I faced same problem, following tutorial resolved my problem https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-11-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Ergghhh... SO discourages the use of screenshots in Q&A in favor of raw text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 49):

```
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

After installing the PostgreSQL database server, by default, it creates a user ‘postgres’ with role ‘postgres’. Also creates a system account with the same name ‘postgres’. So to connect to Postgres server, log in to your system as user postgres and connect database.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

Comment: After `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/lsb_release -cs-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'` I get:
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: @Asmox, the proper command is `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`. You can delete the broken record inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` and then run the command.

Answer (score 19):

First do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You should get no errors upon updating. In case you do, then you might have issues with your firewall, or something blocking you from updating repositories. Check the output carefully.

And then search for the correct (exact!) package name using this command:

```
apt-cache search postgresql
```

As a last resort you could add external 3rd Party repository as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/765546). Just remember to use your distribution name instead of "xenial".

Comment: So I have this: `apt-cache search postgresql | grep client` the only relevant thing that shows up `postgresql-client-10`...so maybe version 11 is not supported on my ubuntu version? how do I find out?

Answer (score 9):

It's Working

It should work.

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting (E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12) while migrating following step may helps you:

```
sudo apt-get -y install bash-completion wget
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | 
sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

ref:[install postgres12 in ubuntu-18.04](https://www.willandskill.se/en/how-to-install-postgres-12-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Following Commands worked for me: sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ lsb_release -cs-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install postgresql-11 libpq-dev
```